# Looking for a work around with out upgrading the Java to 8 or higher support TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 ciphers in Java 1.7.0_79

Tags: java, ssl, handshake

I tried a JCE update on Java 7 as a work around to work with `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384` as higher cipher suites. But I am getting Invalidated

```
%% Invalidated:  [Session-33, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]|#]
```

Certficate unknown, Couldnt figure out.

Any Ideas please ??

Thanks In Advance

Comment: %% Invalidated:  [Session-34, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]|#]
ThreadID=117;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-81-3;|
httpSSLWorkerThread-81-3|#]
ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-81-3;|, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  |#]
[#|2019-05-09T18:01:27.325+0000|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=117;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-81-3;|fatal, |#]
[#|2019-05-09T18:01:27.325+0000|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|me=httpSSLWorkerThread-81-3;|description = certificate_unknown|#]

Comment: [Edit] your question instead of adding comments. Not all comments may be shown initially. Code is unreadable in comments. Please also read [ask], then provide a [mcve].

Comment: Certificate unknown is **separate from and not related to ciphersuite selection**. Look at the certificate (and usually chain) being provided (for a server you can do this manually with `keytool -printcert -sslserver $host[:$port]` but it isn't clear if you are actually having a problem with a client cert, which is harder to look at) and the truststore (or trustmanager) you are using.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't format the error log properly. I am using Java 1.7.0_79 version. Before I updated the JCE to support unlimited policy, I was getting Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384.   After updating the JCE I am getting the Invalidated: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA and end up in the SSL handshake error.

Comment: I resolved this issue by upgrading the JDK from Java 1.7.0_79 to zulu7.29.0.5-ca-jdk7.0.222